# Как уствновить RxJava?

Tags: java, android, rxjava

Подскажите, как установить RxJava. Нигде не могу найти информацию.

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#getting-started

Answer (score 2):

Добавить зависимость compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0' в `build.gradle`
[тут](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) все подробно написано